# Problems seeing my website on iDevice Phonegap

Tags: html, polymer, phonegap-build

I have set up my App vía this terminal command:

```
phonegap create myApp
```

Everything is working fine as long as I leave the default `www/index.html` file untouched. Every time I try to integrate my existing polymer page, the app says

> Note: in order to hear announcements, be sure to turn on your favourite screen reader! Hello, my name is Ava. This true sentence is false. Are you paying attention?

Does anyone know how I can get my polymer (1.0) page up and running?

Comment: Wow, I've come across this statement as well.